# Silverlight: How to force a screen reader to read something?

Tags: c#, silverlight, accessibility, ui-automation, screen-readers

Silverlight does a good job of making the automation tree accessible, but is there a way to programatically ask a screen reader to read something? Up until now I've been using:

```
        AutomationPeer peer = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(element);
        if (peer == null)
        {
            peer = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(element);
        }
        if (peer != null)
        {
            peer.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged);
        }
```

This works fine under the debug Silverlight runtime (ie if I launch IE from inside VS), but doesn't work if I launch IE outside Visual Studio (even when it's pointing to the same internal development server...). So is there another simple way to ask the screen reader to read something?

EDIT: it also works fine in MS Narrator, but not in NVDA... weird.

Comment: Is the element actually focused at this point in time (just before the event it sent) - ie. IsFocused property returning true? Some screenreaders will ignore focus events that are coming from elements that don't appear to be actually focused, and will dismiss them as 'bogus' events. May or may not be the case here, but one thing worth checking.

Comment: No, it's not focused; that was just a hack that seemed to work sometimes. I want to be able to force the screen reader to read something that is _not_ focused (and will never be).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to actually set focus on the element itself. Screen readers track the focus then they read values based on what is focused. If you fire the AutomationFocusChanged event then it might detect that but go back to the same control it had previously.